# utils.hparamsをimportできない

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

こちらのコード(https://github.com/MoonInTheRiver/DiffSinger)をgit cloneしてGoogle Colabで作ったノートブックで環境構築を行い、run.pyを実行したところ2行目の「import utils.hparams」で

```
  File "/content/DiffSinger/tasks/run.py", line 2, in <module>
from utils.hparams import set_hparams, hparams ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.hparams'
```

とエラーが出ました。
色々と調べてカレントディレクトリ関連のエラーかと思い%cdでディレクトリ移動などしてみましたが変わりませんでした。utils.hparamsというのが何のモジュールなのか分かっていないのですが、importする方法をお教えいただけませんか？

Comment: Colab の環境でそのまま使えるのか分かりませんが、参照しているコードのドキュメントに [環境構築の手順](https://github.com/MoonInTheRiver/DiffSinger#environments) が書いてあり、GPU に応じて `pip install -r requirements_2080.txt` または `pip install -r requirements_3090.txt` で必要なモジュールをインストールできるようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。説明不足で申し訳ありません、必要なモジュールはpipで` pip install -r requirements_3090.txt `インストールしたにもかかわらずimportできないという状況になっています。